# EventTrigger on a TextBlock that sets a Border - Cannot resolve all property references

Tags: wpf, path, properties

I have a Custom control in WPF in which I define a large ItemsControl Template. 
In there, I have a Grid and in one column of that grid, I got a TextBlock and in another column I have a Border.

I want to highlight the Border when the mouse enters the TextBlock.

I tried several scenarios: 
first an `EventTrigger` in the TextBlock's Style, but I learned that you can't do that, then an EventTrigger within the TextBlock's Triggers section, and now I just put it in the DataTemplate.Triggers of my ItemsControl, but I keep getting the error:

```
"Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Border.BorderBrush.Color'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties."
```

Here is the code that causes trouble:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger SourceName="mytxtblock" RoutedEvent="TextBlock.MouseEnter">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myborder"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.BorderBrush.Color"
                                                Duration="0:0:1"                                                                        
                                                To="White" />
                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.BorderThickness"
                                                    Duration="0:0:1"
                                                    From="0"
                                                    To="1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

I think I'm missing something about the way i refer to the Color property of my Border, any insight?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I figured out that declaring a `SolidColorBrush` in `Resources` and then using that value allows me to get rid of the

`Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.BorderBrush.Color"` that changes to `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.BorderBrush"`,

but now the compiler tells me that the color i declared (i tried Green and Transparent) is not a valid value for "To"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<ColorAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="myborder"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
    Duration="0:0:1"
    To="White" />
```

but you have to declare a `BorderBrush`

```
BorderBrush="whatever"
```

or

```
<Border.BorderBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="whatever" />
</Border.BorderBrush>
```

in your "myborder" too.

Comment: I get an exception: 'BorderBrush' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path 'BorderBrush.(0)'.

Comment: I may never get the hang of WPF binding paths, but "BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" worked for my UserControl's border, so thanks!

Comment: (EDIT) it's a XAML PropertyPath, not a binding path as I stated above. Posting this in case it helps anyone else's search for enlightenment.

Comment: The small "issue" of not having declared/set a value on my "BorderBrush" property is what I was missing. 6 years on in WPF/XAML, and still learning!

Answer (score 0):

On your `ColorAnimation` there are two properties:

```
Storyboard.TargetName="myborder"
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.BorderBrush.Color"
```

It implies, that `myborder` has a property called `Border`. I think that causes your error.