# Change the textblock's background depending on click

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two questions here:

1.

Lets look at the xaml below:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="LightBlue" Duration="0:0:0.100" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<TextBlock Text="123" />
<TextBlock Text="abc" />
```

Current behavior of the above code:

When I click on the textblock with text = 123, its background is changed to LightBlue.
Now if I click on the textblock with text = abc, its background is changed to LightBlue. But the background of textblock with text = 123 remains LightBlue.

Requirements:

I want to change the background of textblock with text = 123 to Transparent when I click on the textBlock with text = abc.

What changes should I make to the above xaml to get the required functionality?

2.

How to set TargetType of a same Style for multiple elements.

Lets say,

I want to use the style mentioned in the above code for TextBox also, then How can I use it without repeating code and also without using x:Key attribute?

Answer (score 2):

*For the first question:* I think this would be easy to implement from code-behind, by using the event GotFocus, which is the event fired when you click on a textbox by either keyboard, mouse etc...

*For the second question:* You can set the target Type of multiple different controls, by setting  the TargetType to their parent class, for example `TargetType="{x:Type Control}"`

For more information (Almost the same case scenario), please check:

[Can you define multiple TargetTypes for one XAML style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802658/can-you-define-multiple-targettypes-for-one-xaml-style)

Comment: Thanks, +1 for answer to second question.

Comment: For the first question: I think this would be easy to implement from code-behind, by using the event `GotFocus`, which is the event fired when you click on a textbox by either keyboard, mouse etc..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I would like to do it in xaml.

Comment: Why don't you check this post, I think this may solve the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008532/eventtrigger-on-a-textblock-that-sets-a-border-cannot-resolve-all-property-ref

Comment: No, that post is not specific to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Though Nirvana Priest has answered second question .the answer for first question is Write the same trigger for LostFocus like

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="LightBlue" Duration="0:0:0.100" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.100" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Nope, it does not make any change to the output. I have tried to set transparent in LostFocus.

Comment: I have also tried GotFocus instead of MouseDown, it is also not working.

Comment: Oh sorry I am doing it for TextBox and You doing it for TextBlock.

Comment: Did you find any solution for textblock?

Comment: Try MouseLeave instead of LostFocus

Comment: No, I don't want to use MouseLeave as my users will have to set some properties on the selected eelement.

Comment: Khushi mere bhai mila koi jugad :) .

Comment: ab tak to kuch nahi mila.